# Can CPLEX or Gurobi mathematical programming packages handle this objective function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, solver, gurobi

I have the following objective function in a formulation.

[image: formula]

The [image: formula]'s are 0-1 variables and the [image: formula]'s are constants.

I know that packages like CPLEX and Gurobi can handle quadratic objective functions and constraints. However, the above objective function has variables in the denominator and it appears to me that standard mathematical programming packages cannot handle this.

I would like to know if I am correct, and if not, I would love some pointers on how I might express such an objective function in a .LP file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first term `sum(i, (s(i)*x(i,j))^2 )` is actually linear, as `x^2=x` for a binary variable. So this is just `sum(i, s(i)^2*x(i,j))`.

The ratio is more difficult. It can be rewritten as

```
 ratio(j)*sum(i,x(i,j)) = sum(i,s(i)*x(i,j))^2
```

For sure this can be handled by Gurobi as it allows non-convex quadratic terms anywhere in the model (i.e. both the objective and constraints). So my first try would be:

```
 min sum(j, w2(j) - ratio(j))         (linear)
 v(j) = sum(i,x(i,j))                 (linear)  
 w(j) = sum(i,s(i)*x(i,j))            (linear)  
 w2(j) =  sum(i, s(i)^2*x(i,j))       (linear)
 ratio(j)*v(j) = w(j)^2               (quadratic)
```

and use Gurobi's nonconvex quadratic solver. Of course, we don't know the rest of the model which may yield further possibilities to simplify this.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Erwin! The superb observations in your answer really cleared up things for me. I will try this out!

Comment: The suggested formulation runs into a problem when 
sum(i, x(i,j)) is zero for some j. In this case both v(j) and w(j) become 0  and ratio(j) can be increased without bound. Gurobi reports an unbounded model. I am unable to think of a way to modify the model such that the quadratic constraint above kicks in only when v(j) > 0. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have seen that before. My trick: Introduce an intermediate variable z for the objective, and put some large bounds on it.

Comment: Of course another simple fix would be to put a lower bound of 1 on v(j).

Comment: Creating a variable for the objective function worked like a charm! I did not even have to place a constraint on the variable. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the nature of my problem, I cannot place a lower bound of 1 on v(j).

Comment: Yes you can, because you divide by it in your original problem statement.

Comment: I had overlooked this in my original statement and that is what was causing the unboundedness. I now have indicator constraints that force ratio(j) to zero if v(j) is zero and enable the quadratic constraint above only when v(j) is 1. The model is now working correctly in Gurobi. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

with CPLEX you may rely on MP and try what Erwin suggested.
You may also use CPOptimizer and then you do not need to remodel.

You can directly for instance if you use the OPL API write

```
using CP;

int n=4;
int m=5;

int s[1..n]=[1,2,3,8];
dvar boolean x[1..n][1..m];


minimize 
  sum(j in 1..m)(
   sum(i in 1..n)(s[i]*x[i][j])^2-
   (sum(i in 1..n)(x[i][j]*s[i]))^2/sum(i in 1..n)x[i][j]);
subject to
{
  
}
```

which works fine

Comment: thanks a lot!  This seems very attractive too. I will try both and report back.